# How do I set default progress bar color and background colour for tqdm?

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

I'm using tqdm in a Jupiter notebook.  Normally I would see a green progress bar on a white background.  However, now I see a black progress bar on a pink background:

```
import tqdm, tqdm.notebook
from time import sleep

# first progress bar
for i in tqdm.notebook.tqdm(range(10)):
    sleep(.1)

# second progress bar
for i in tqdm.notebook.tqdm(range(10)):
    sleep(.1)
    
# third progress bar
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(10)):
    sleep(.1)
    
# fourth progress bar
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(10), colour='green'):
    sleep(.1)
```

produces these four bars:

[image]

What I want is a green progress bar, without the pink background.

This change in behaviour appeared after I installed PyQt5. I've uninstalled but behaviour remains.

Also, previously I used `tqdm.notebook.tqdm` in my notebook for progress bars.  Now that function does not display a progress bar (bars 1 and 2). I need to use `tqdm.tqdm` (bars 3 and 4).

I assume the issue is something to do with the backend.

Answer (score 5):

the pink background means that the output goes to `sys.stderr`. To have white background use tqdm parameter `file`. To change color use parameter `colour`:

`for i in tqdm(range(50), file=sys.stdout, colour='GREEN'):`

see more info in [tqdm docs](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/)